# Play framework compilation issues with dependencies

Tags: scala, playframework-2.3

I'm having issues with running a simple scala play app with a few dependencies. The below is happening when trying to run my app.

```
[error] /Users/roland/play-scala/app/domain/UserModule.scala:2: 
          object softwaremill is not a member of package com
[error] import com.softwaremill.macwire.MacwireMacros.wire
```

UserModule:

```
package domain
import com.softwaremill.macwire.MacwireMacros.wire

trait UserModule {


  lazy val userRepository = wire[UserRepository]
  lazy val userService = wire[UserService]
}
```

and my build.sbt is

```
name := """play-scala"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.10.3"

resolvers += "Maven Central Server" at "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2"

resolvers += "Neo4j Scala Repo" at "http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases"

resolvers += "Sonatype Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache,
  ws,
  "org.webjars" % "coffee-script-node" % "1.7.1",
  "net.liftweb" %% "lift-json" % "3.0-SNAPSHOT",
  "eu.fakod" %% "neo4j-scala" % "0.3.1-SNAPSHOT",
  "com.softwaremill.macwire" %% "macros" % "0.7.3",
  "com.softwaremill.macwire" %% "runtime" % "0.7.3"
)
```

It seems to be totally fine when looking at it in intellij idea and looking in my ivy cache I have the dependencies there but the application when it runs through the play console seems to be very unhappy. Sorry for the lack of info but im quite new to scala and play so been struggling all day with this issue.

Comment: Did you try replacing %% with % in dependency?

Comment: Don't think that would fix it. My understanding is that %% appends the scala version which in this case I believe is 2.10 and I can see macros_2.10 in the maven repo?

Comment: If you do a `clean` and `update` in `sbt`, does it give you any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed the maven repo is named `macros_2.10` but there is `scalaVersion := "2.10.3"` in build.sbt

Try to remove this line.